# Showing a component when clicking a button

Tags: reactjs

I know this should be simple enough, but I'm having trouble getting the button below to show the data from my API call when clicking the button. It worked when I loaded the API data on the click, but since adjusting the logic to load the API data on the page load, and then display it when clicking the button, I'm not able to get it to display at all despite no errors.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import rsLogo from "./logo-with-name.png";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import CollapsibleTable from "./Table";
function App() {
  const [balldontlie, setBalldontlie] = React.useState([]);
  const [weather, setWeather] = React.useState({});
  const [showTeams, setShowTeams] = React.useState(false);
  const onShowTeamsClick = () => {
    setShowTeams(!showTeams);
  };
  const fetchListWeather = (row) => {
    let param = `?key=somekey=${row.city}`;
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "somewebsite" + param,
    }).then(function (response) {
      setWeather(response.data);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!balldontlie) {
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "somewebsite",
      }).then(
        function (response) {
          setBalldontlie(response.data);
        },
        [balldontlie]
      );
    }
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={rsLogo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      </header>
      <main>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          target="_blank"
          onClick={() => {
            onShowTeamsClick();
          }}
          size="large"
          sx={{ m: 2, bgcolor: "#00003C" }}
        >
          List Teams
        </Button>
        {showTeams ? (
          <div>
            <CollapsibleTable
              fetchListWeather={fetchListWeather}
              weather={weather}
              balldontlie={balldontlie}
            />
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Was that useEffect working before?

Answer (score 0):

Use the function version of set state when using the same state you are setting.

Instead of

```
setShowTeams(!showTeams);
```

Do

```
setShowTeams((previousStateValue) => !previousStateValue);
```

This is a stale state problem and you can read more about it here
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

"If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value. "

Comment: Thank you, I did update it with that syntax but I'm still not able to render the component. Is there something else I'm missing besides changing it to setShowTeams((current) => !current)?

Comment: Possibly? I don't know what's in your other component but I don't see the function fetchListWeather being invoked- i see it passed to a child, but whether the child is re-rendering when data loads, I cannot tell  =)  Stick just some div in there to see if the show button is working, and if it is, move on to troubleshoot pulling the actual data?